# Double negation vs. law of excluded middle?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, axioms

I think I am operating under classic logic here, or propositional logic? Not sure if these are the same thing or what all the options are here.

When I see how to prove double negation elimination, it uses law of excluded middle. When I see how to prove law of excluded middle, it uses double negation elimination.

Are these two things considered equivalent and axiomatic or is there some other proof that handles both? If it is an axiom, what other axioms exist?

Comment: "Classical" and "propositional" are adjectives. There is classical propositional logic, intuitionistic propositional logic, classical predicate logic, intuitionististic predicate logic, and a large (ultimately infinite) variety of other logics. There are also many different presentations of the same logic. Some presentations of classical propositional logic may take the Law of Excluded Middle as an axiom, while others take double negation elimination or something else as an axiom.

Comment: I'm not sure what resources you are looking at. The [Wikipedia page on propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) gives several presentations. "Reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity" sounds like you're thinking about laws for equality which is orthogonal to propositional logic. Based on your recent questions, you may get something out of [my post about the pedagogy of logic](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/the-pedagogy-of-logic-a-rant.html). Unfortunately, it is more designed to shake assumptions and provide perspective rather than to teach content.

Comment: Is there a list containing the propositional axioms? Are most things based in classical or intuitionistic?

Comment: If you write "When I see ...", you are referring to references that you have not given us. I vote to close as you have not given enough context.

Comment: @RobArthan I think I had confused it with the wiki article on axioms of equality, but even on the wiki for prepositional calculus I'm not clear on axioms and how it relates to DNE/LEM. I edited my post to remove that paragraph.

Comment: Well fix your question! Identify the conflicting references that are giving you a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a propositional logic, the sentences are built out of primative abstract sentences $A_1,A_2,\ldots $ by combining them with connectives. The usual set of connectives are $\{\lnot,\land,\lor,\to, \leftrightarrow\},$ though sometimes a smaller set is used (or a smaller set is taken as primative and the others are defined off of them). Sometimes also there are other connectives too (e.g. in modal propositional logic), but since we're only really focusing on classical and intuitionistic here, which only use the ones I mentioned.

So things like $A_1\to A_2$ and $A_1\lor \lnot A_3$ would be sentences. Here we would write the law of excluded middle as $$ \mathcal A \lor \lnot\mathcal A$$ where it's understood that we can substitute any given sentence for $\mathcal A.$ Such a substitution is called an *instance* of LEM, so, for instance $ (A_1\land A_2)\lor \lnot(A_1\land A_2)$ is an instance of LEM.

The thing that makes the system "propositional" as opposed to, say, a predicate logic is that the basic building blocks are these primative abstract sentences $A_i.$ In predicate logic, the atomic sentences themselves have structure, and we have variables and constants representing individuals, and relation symbols representing relations between individuals (like equality), and quantifiers. For instance, you've probably seen things like $$\forall x_1 \forall x_2((x_1<x_2)\land (x_2<x_1)).$$ This is a sentence in predicate logic (that is also false in its usual interpretation as a sentence about numbers).

Predicate logic is related to propositional logic cause we can still write things like LEM $$ \mathcal A \lor \lnot\mathcal A,$$ where now we will substitute sentences of predicate calculus in for $\mathcal A$ to generate instances. So we can talk about the LEM in either context. From now on, I'll stick to propositional logic.

Now, we've talked about the grammar, but we still haven't said what these sentences are for. Of course we know that we intend $A_1\to A_2 $ to mean what "if $A_1$, then $A_2$" informally means and $A_1\land A_2$ to mean "$A_1$ and $A_2$", etc. We want is to be able to prove certain sentences valid, for instance, clearly we would like to be able to show somehow $A_1\to A_1$... this is clearly something that "should" be valid.

So we need a deductive system, which consists of rules for taking valid sentences and producing new valid sentences, as well as axioms, sentences we assume are valid. There are tons of different ways to do this: the main systems fall into three categories: Hilbert-style systems, natural deduction, and sequent calculus. No time to explain what these are, of course, other than to say a natural deduction system will be most convenient for our purposes here, so that's the category you're seeing here, though it will usually be presented much more formally (and carefully).

In this, we will take as a primative axiom scheme that $\mathcal A\to \mathcal A$ is valid where anything is substituted for $\mathcal A.$ This will be the only axiom, and everything else will be rules. (EDIT: I actually don't think this axiom scheme is even necessary since every instance of it follows from the $\to$ introduction rule described below.)

For instance, we have an introduction rule for $\lor$ that if a sentence $\phi$ is valid then $\phi\lor \psi$ and $\psi \lor \phi$ are valid for any sentence $\psi.$ Then we have an elimination rule, that if from the assumption of validity of a sentence $\phi$, we can derive that $\psi$ is valid, and separately, if from the assumption of the validity of a sentence $\phi',$ we can derive that same $\psi$ is valid, and $\phi\lor \phi'$ is valid, then $\psi$ is valid.

We can define similar introduction and elimination rules for $\land$... I won't mention what they are for lack of space: they're easier than the ones for $\lor$ and you can probably figure out what they are. Then there is an introduction rule for $\to$: if starting with a hypothetical assumption of $\phi,$ we can derive that $\psi$ is valid, then $\phi\to \psi $ is valid. And then the elimination rule is that if both $\phi$ and $\phi\to \psi$ are valid, then $\psi$ is valid.

Finally, we come to negation. First off, it is most convenient to not take negation as primative, but rather to take special primative sentence $\bot$ which intuitively represents a false statement or a contradiction. Then we define negation as $\lnot \mathcal \phi = \mathcal \phi\to \bot.$ Then we have an elimination rule for $\bot$ that from $\bot$ we can infer any sentence, which formalizes the notion that from an absurdity, we can derive anything. There is no introduction rule for $\bot.$

Notice this gels with our intuitive idea of contradiction, because if we have $\phi$ and $\lnot \phi,$ which recall is just an abbreviation for $\phi\to \bot,$ then by $\to$ elimination, we infer that $\bot$ is valid.

These rules give a version of the deductive system for *intuitionistic* propositional logic. Any statement whose validity can be proven by these rules is called intuitionistically valid. As I mentioned before, there are many different types of deductive systems that all produce the same valid sentences... I have only given one example.

Now, here's where we finally get down to answering your question. We can convince ourselves that we can neither prove $A_1 \lor \lnot A_1$ nor $\lnot\lnot A_1 \to A_1$ from the above rules. (It's a bit more complicated than this if we want to be careful, but the basic idea for LEM is that in order to get $A_1\lor\lnot A_1,$ we'd need to use the introduction rule for $\lor,$ which requires that we have either $A_1$ or $\lnot A_1$ valid. And it's clear, since $A_1$ is just some abstract sentence, there's no way of proving either of these things.)

So the schemes $\mathcal A \lor \lnot \mathcal A$ and $\lnot\lnot \mathcal A \to \mathcal A$ are not generally valid under intuitionistic logic. However, we can show that by taking either one of these schemes as an axiom, we can derive every instance of the other. So LEM and double negation elimination are equivalent over intuitionistic propositional logic. Adding either of these as an axiom results in classical propositional logic.

Comment: Actually, classical propositional logic differs from intuitionistic already at $\to$: Peirce's law $((P\to Q)\to P)\to P$ is classically but not intuitionistically valid.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point... edited that out. I was just referring to the fact that all the rules were the same up to there cause I was originally going to do different negation elimination rules, but then ended up doing it the way with $\bot$ instead and extending with axioms instead

Comment: @HenningMakholm Actually if I'd seen your answer and comments appear as I wrote this, I'd have probably aborted (for some reason the website isn't always pushing updates as well as it used to for me). It's always odd to me when people prove two classically valid things are equivalent in classical logic and act as if that means something without a much longer discussion.

Comment: Well, it sounds like the OP will be interested in your more detailed sketch of intuitionistic logic, so it's not like it's wasted effort.

Comment: I'm trying to read my way through this but it's taking me some time to absorb... how are we defining "valid"? How are we defining how these connectives work without being circular?

Comment: @user525966  1. We are defining 'valid' as being provable within the system described: i.e. either an axiom or following from other valid statements by the rules of deduction. (In classical logic, validity is usually defined semantically (e.g. from truth tables) and then shown to coincide with provability with a completeness theorem. Here we don't bother with semantics since the semantics of intuitionistic logic is more complicated and would be a bridge too far to discuss.) 2. We have defined how the connectives work with the intro/elim rules. What is circular?

Comment: I'm just getting lost by the time I get halfway into this post, I can't tell what's an axiom and what's something else, etc. Like when we say "introduction rule" I don't really know what this is. What's the difference between an axiom and a rule, or a definition, etc?

Comment: @user525966 An axiom is a statement we are assuming is valid. An inference rule is a rule that allows us to prove that a new statement valid based on some other validities we have shown. "introduction" and "elimination" are just suggestive names that say that the conclusion has a new connective in it compared to the premises it was derived from, or that it has one fewer.

Comment: @user525966 Maybe I should have started with the $\land$ intro/elim rules cause they are the easiest. 1) If $A$ is valid and $B$ is valid, then $A\land B$ is valid. 2) If $A\land B$ is valid, then $A$ is valid. Similarly, if $A\land B$ is valid then $B$ is valid. Does that make sense? Notice in 1) the conclusion has a new $\land$ in it that wasn't in the premises (thus an introduction of a $\land$) and in 2) the conclusion has one fewer connective than the premises (a $\land$ has been eliminated).

Comment: So the only axiom we have is $A \implies A$ and somehow we can get $a \land b$ and $b \land a$?

Comment: @user525966 No... How could we get $A\land B$? If we have $A$ and we have $B$ then we can get $A\land B$... that's what the rule says. Do we have $A$? Do we have $B$? This tells us whether we have $A\land B$ or not.

Comment: I'm totally lost on all this again then. Because you say we start out with that one axiom and then you immediately move to this "introduction rule" for $\land$ which you say is not an axiom but rather a new statement that is valid based on some other validities shown, but up until this point we don't have other validities, just the single axiom.

Comment: We have $A\to A$ is valid. So the $\land$ introduction tells us that $(A\to A)\land(A\to A)$ is valid. And then we can apply it again to show $((A\to A)\land (A\to A))\land (A\to A)$ is valid.

Comment: But we haven't defined what $\land$ is yet, no?

Comment: @user525966 $\land$ is just a symbol. When we give the inference rules we are giving information about the validity of sentences involving that symbol. Notice that we were able to say some sentences involving $\land$ were valid by invoking the introduction rule. These rules correspond to the symbol "meaning" what the word "and" informally means, of course, which is why we chose the rules in the way we did. It would be useful to study the distinction between syntax and semantics in logic

Comment: But why do we know $(A\to A)\land(A\to A)$ is valid when we haven't defined what $\land$ does? We know $A \to A$ is valid because we've defined it as an axiom. But how are we showing how $\land$ works?

Comment: @user525966 We **have** defined what $\land$ does... That is what the introduction and elimination rules are. We know it is valid because it follows from the fact that $A\to A$ is valid, and from the $\land$-introduction rule.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult but I am not getting this. Are we **defining** what $\land$ does in terms of $A \to A$ somehow?

Comment: @user525966 No. We are defining what $\land$ does by the following introduction rule: "If the sentence $\phi$ is valid and the sentence $\psi$ is valid, then the sentence $\phi\land \psi$ is valid." Now, take $\phi$ to be the sentence $A\to A$ and $\psi$ to also be the sentence $A\to A.$ We know (from the axiom scheme) that $A\to A$ is valid. So $\phi$ is valid and $\psi$ is valid. Therefore, by the $\land$-introduction rule, $\phi\land \psi$ is valid. So, replacing $\phi$ and $\psi$ by what they stand for $(A\to A)\land (A\to A)$ is valid.

Comment: @user525966 We could have also taken $\psi$ to be the valid $B\to B$ and gotten from $\land$ introduction that $(A\to A)\land(B\to B)$ is valid. (There is the elimination rule too that allows us to 'run this reasoning backwards', but let's start with the intro).

Comment: Ok, with you on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82602/discussion-between-spaceisdarkgreen-and-user525966).

Answer (score 3):

Double-negation elimination and the law of excluded middle are both things that *happen to be true* in the semantics we *want* for classical propositional logic -- defined, for example, by truth tables and how to evaluate a proposition under a given truth assignment.

When we construct a *proof system* for the logic we want that proof system to be able to prove both double-negation elimination and the law of excluded middle (because they are semantically valid and we want the proof system to prove everything that is semantically valid).

Often this is ensured by considering *either* double-negation elimination *or* excluded middle as a primitive proof step.

The proofs you have seen of "DNE implies LEM" and "LEM implies DNE" are not supposed to convince you that the principles are *valid* -- truth tables are much better for that. The worth of those proof is merely that they show **if one of these principles is allowed as a primitive proof step, then the other doesn't need to be**.

(It is also not uncommon that *neither* of these principles are primitive proof step, but something else an equivalent is used instead. For example, this could be a primitive rule for proof-by-contradiction, or $(P\to Q)\to(\neg P\lor Q)$ or the "reverse contraposition" rule $(\neg Q\to \neg P)\to(P\to Q)$ can be declared to be a logical axiom. Then both DNE and LEM can be derived from *that*).

> I ask because when I look up logic axioms I only see basic stuff like reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity, etc, but nothing like double negation or law of excluded middle.

There are many equivalent ways to construct a proof system for classical propositional logic. They have different sets of logical axioms, but they can all prove exactly the same conclusions.

So it does not make sense to ask whether this-or-that formula is a logical axiom *in general*. You can only ask whether it is a logical axiom *in such-and-such proof system*.

If you try to google a list of logical axioms, you will find several lists. Some of them will, as is the nature of google results, be misunderstood or nonsense. But each of the ones that *aren't* will belong to a particular proof system. And it may not always be clear in the context you find that this is the case.

Comment: How do you derive DNE and EM from "implies"? (and as far as I know, contraposition can be proved from "implies" itself. p -> q, means not p or q, means q or not p, means not q -> not p). Also isn't it $(\neg Q\to \neg P)\iff(P\to Q)$?

Comment: @user525966: Surprisingly it turns out that the single direction $(\neg Q\to \neg P)\to(P\to Q)$ is enough to derive everything, if you just have Modus Ponens and the Deduction Theorem. It will give you DNE and EM _and_ its own converse as well as introduction and elimination rules for $\neg$ all in one breath. But I don't remember _how_ that works well enough to even sketch it.

Comment: Is $\leftrightarrow$ itself considered an axiomatic relation? For example when you say $(P\to Q)\leftrightarrow(\neg P\lor Q)$ is an axiom it's still using $\leftrightarrow$ which in itself is an operator with its own truth table, etc.

Comment: @user525966: Hmm, no, $A\leftrightarrow B$ usually is an abbreviation for $(A\to B)\land(B\to A)$. So in addition to what I said you would also need the intuitionistic rules for $\land$. Though, after thinking about it a bit more I think it would actually be enough to add $(P\to Q)\to(\neg P\lor Q)$; the other direction can be derived from the intuitionistic rules.

Comment: When you are saying "intuitionistic rules" is this referring to something specific? I'm still not quite sure what this even means, or "intuitionistic rules" for $\land$, etc.

Comment: @user525966: Sorry -- intuitionistic logic means logic that _doesn't_ accept DNE/EM etc, so the intuitionistic rules would basically be everything else in your proof system that tells how to handle those other connectives in proofs.

Comment: I'm sorry the discussion here in the comments about how those alternative axioms would work got a bit technical, and assumes a bit more knowledge than I did in the main answer.

Comment: Is that the only real difference between classical and intuitionistic logic? Taking DNE/EM as an axiom vs not? How can intuitionistic logic prove anything without those laws being assumed? Can DNE/EM be proven in intuitionistic logic or is it just taken as an unprovable yet well-formed statement?

Comment: @HenningMakholm One issue is often (especially for Hilbert-style presentation) the rules are fairly minimal and simply dropping DNE or EM or whatever produces a logical system that's far weaker than constructive logic. This is one of the reasons I like more structural presentations like the sequent calculus or natural deduction which isolate the rules for the connectives from each other.

Comment: @user525966: Yes, that is the only difference between classical and intuitionistic logic. See spaceisdarkgreen's excellent answer for a brief sketch of a possible proof system for intuitionistic logic -- there are plenty of rules that are _not_ DNE/LEM which can prove _some_ tautologies such as $P\to P$ or $(P\to(Q\to R))\to(Q\to(P\to R))$.

Comment: I am really confused here... how many systems are we talking? Propositional, Hilbert, intuitionistic, structural, sequent, natural deduction, classical, etc?

Comment: @user525966 - Logic is a pretty big field with a lot of technical depth, like a lot of areas. Don't expect yourself to understand all of these things in one go.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Is LEM an axiom in either a Hilbert or natural deduction framework? Are these flavors also on top of institutioniatic? For example a Hilbert style institutioniatic propositional framework, or natural deductive classical propositional framework, etc. Trying to better understand how this stuff is organized and described.

Comment: @user525966: It could be either, though in a natural deduction system one would typically choose a rule that has an implication so it can be framed as a deduction rule rather than an axiom.

Comment: @user525966: And there are both intuitionistic and classical variants of all of Hilbert systems, natural deduction or sequent calculus.

Comment: Sequent is different from both Hilbert style and natural deduction? Hilbert to my understanding is more axioms, fewer rules of inf, natural has a lot of rules of inf bit no axioms.

Comment: @user525966: Yes, sequent calculus is a third style. It is somewhat less intuitive than the two others, but offers some technical benefits that one needs a fair amount of experience with the matter to really appreciate,

Comment: Added later: my initial argument (in a now deleted comment) that $(P\to Q)\to(\neg P\lor Q)$ gives classical logic was hopelessly and needlessly convoluted. Much easier is: If $(P\to Q)\to(\neg P \lor Q)$ holds in general, then in particular $(A\to A)\to(\neg A\lor A)$, and since $A\to A$ is trivially provable, this gives us the law of excluded middle immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\neg P\vee P$ is an axiom as well as implication ($A\to B \iff \neg A\vee B)$ and assume that our system allows modus ponens (If $A$ and $A\to B$ hold then $B$).  Lastly $C\iff D$ is short for $(C\to D)\wedge (D\to C$). We also need simplification of conjugation (to the left): This says if $C\wedge D$ then $C$.

> (1) $\neg P\vee P$ : Axiom (Law of Excluded Middle)
>
> (2) $ \ \neg P\vee P \iff (\neg\neg P\to P)$ : Axiom (Implication)
>
> (2*) $ \neg P\vee P \to (\neg\neg P\to P) \wedge (\neg\neg P\to P) \to (\neg P\vee P)$ this is line (2) written out in full.
>
> (3) $ \neg P\vee P \to (\neg\neg P\to P)$
>
> (4) $\therefore \neg\neg P \to P : by$  MP applied to lines (1) and (3)

I'm not sure how you can do this in any more of a minimalistic manner.... or why you would want to; but I guess you're just curious.

Hope that helps... if you have any questions, I'll try to answer.

Comment: So then implication, $A\to B \iff \neg A\vee B$, how is this proven outside of a truth table? Or is this considered an axiom too?

Comment: @user525966 Truth tables aren't about proof. They are about validity (and even then, only for classical propositional logic, not for classical predicate logic or non-classical logics). The soundness and completeness theorems for classical propositional logic connects validity and provability, but this is a meta-theorem and requires an (a priori) unrelated notion of formal proof.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. People use truth tables all the time to show / prove that something works.

Comment: @user525966 yes.  This is also an axiom.  Truth tables give us "semantic" truths (provided you start with a few tautologies), and proofs give us "syntactic" truths (provided you start with axioms).

You confusion exists because you are using "proof" in the common usage (whereas people here have a lot more experience in logic and for them "proof" is burned in them to mean "there exists a deduction from axioms for this proposition".  In first order logic syntax and semantics are equivalent ... but only because of the axioms we chose.

Comment: Some definitions:  A tautology is any proposition that is true on a truth table no matter what truth value you give to each of its parts (for example $\neg P\vee P$).  When we build an axiomatic system, we include all tautologies as part of our list of axioms (there are other axioms but this is getting off topic).  This is why in my answer above I asserted a few axioms. 

It seems you are stumbling on something important:  We cannot prove anything without at least a few basic assumptions and rules to connect things.  Related is the following:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Münchhausen_trilemma

Comment: So in propositional calculus, truth tables don't prove anything, they just show... truths ("semantically"), whereas proving something ("syntactically") is done by manipulating the logical statements themselves? Does this mean everything in logic can be shown/proven without needing to resort to truth tables? Like for example normally I'd define the $\land$ operator by saying "here's its truth table, these are all $4$ cases", we can "prove" this some other way?

Comment: No they do "prove" things.  The soundness and completeness theorems that other people are talking about is a meta-logic theorem (a theorem $about$ logic as opposed to $within$ in it) .... and the soundness and completeness theorems show us that if you can prove something syntactically you can prove it semantically and visa versa.  But things fall apart outside first order logic

Comment: A little confused then because @DerekElkins above said they don't prove things. But if something can be shown with truth tables then it can be shown without it, and vice-versa? I'm also a little lost on whether meta-logic is a formal thing or what are the theorems, etc.

Comment: Meta-logic is a SUPER formal thing.  And it becomes quite difficult: Think Gödel's theorems and the like.  If you are curious about what it means to "prove" something.  You should maybe ask a separate question, because you're now drifting from the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Two basic equivalences in classical logic are:

**Double Negation**

$$P \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg P$$

**Implication**

$$P \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$$

Thus, we have:

$$\neg P \lor P \Leftrightarrow P \rightarrow P \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg P \rightarrow P$$

Does that help?

Comment: This seems circular.  You're actually assuming both and then showing that they are logically equivalent.

Comment: Not sure I follow what this is trying to show? Seems like it's starting out with something and proving a weaker form of itself? And which aspect is the axiom?

Comment: It's trying to show the final line:  Law of excluded middle if and only if P implies itself if and only if Double Negation is a law.  The far left and the far right of the final equation are what we use (in a deduction) to replace Truth with ~P or P and ~~P with P.

Comment: Law of excluded middle though is "p and not p = false" I thought? Or I guess same as "not p or p = true" if we apply demorgans laws but then that's invoking another thing to prove. I'm still not sure I'm following the explanation though. It's showing how you get from one to the other if we assume they work, if I understand correctly.

Comment: you are confusing it with law of noncontradiction.

Comment: @user525966 It's showing that they are equivalent, assuming Double Negation and Implication as 'axioms'. So it's not assuming that they work, but that they imply each other

Comment: @Squirtle What do you mean? What am I confusing where?

Comment: @Bram28 I know they imply each other, but are they considered axioms or can they be proven?

Comment: @user525966 anything provable is admissible as an axiom and any axiom is provable. So your question needs to be qualified in order to make sense, and even after that, the answer will usually be 'it depends'.

Comment: This is all so freaking confusing. It's like there isn't a clear set of axioms just taken to be true in any of this, it's all this big circular whirlwind

Comment: @user525966 It's not but it's easy to see why it might appear that way when there are so many different systems and so many subtleties. I attempted to give a 'crash course' in my answer of the sense in which it makes sense  to say lem and dne are equivalent (relative to an intuituionistic system where they aren't provable), and hopefully this will also give some context as to the big picture. But honestly, it's just something that takes time to learn properly, going slow and looking at a variety of sources.